# Carriage Returns removal

Tags: excel, vba

I have following code:

```
Sub RemoveCarriageReturns()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 
    For Each MyRange In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If 0 < InStr(MyRange, Chr(10)) Then
            MyRange = Replace(MyRange, Chr(10), "")
        End If
    Next
 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

and it works fine, but lately i am came across some files that have multiple carriage returns in one cell.
How can i modify this code to include possibility for more then one carriage return in a cell?
Thank you,
Inna

Comment: `MyRange = Replace(MyRange, Chr(10), "")` will replace all the returns in that cell not just the first.

Comment: But you do not need to loop to do this.  A simple: `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Replace Chr(10), ""` will remove them all in one command.

Comment: Yet `Chr(10)` is a line feed not a carriage return. Normally they are paired. `.replace(MyRange, vbcrlf, "")`

Comment: Could you explain why you are replacing it with an empty string, while it should make more sense to replace it with a space (last word above - space - first word below)? You may want to replace `vbCrLf` first and only then `vbLf` since it's unlikely that you have solo `vbCr` characters.

Comment: Scott thank you, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Replace Chr(10), "" worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace

```
        If 0 < InStr(MyRange, Chr(10)) Then
            MyRange = Replace(MyRange, Chr(10), "")
        End If
```

with

```
        Do While 0 < InStr(MyRange, Chr(10)) 
            MyRange = Replace(MyRange, Chr(10), "")
        Loop
```

Comment: I tried this code but I am getting error msg Compile error: expected end of statement on the first line: Do While 0 < InStr(MyRange, Chr(10)) Then

Comment: I had forgotten to remove "Then". Sorry: please try again.